# Identification of butterfly from caterpillar

Tags: zoology, botany, entomology

i visited a butterfly house and they didn't know which butterfly will be the caterpillars in the picture, my first guess is 'papilio aegeus'. I think the eggs/ caterpillars were on a 'paulownia tomentosa' plant, but i'm not sure. (Identified with the app 'flora incognita)
My first guess would be papilio aegeus.

Thanks to all answering and helping me out.

[image: Caterpillar (younger ones)]

[image: Caterpillar (older ones)]

[image: Close up Caterpillar]

Comment: I'm sure you meant to add the picture (it's surprising how often people forget). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. It'd be helpful if there's some idea of scale to the creature if possible.

Comment: Yes the pictures are missing, i deleted them on accident, but added them now. I'm sorry and thank you for telling me. For scale i just can say they are 2-5 mm.

Comment: Where and when were these pictures taken? What is the size of the critter?

Comment: Like i wrote the pictures are taken in a butterfly house and the caterpillar is 5mm. It was 4 days ago. 
Butterfly houses mainly don't have food plants for the caterpillars, so the butterflies are laying eggs on not suitable plants.